# Start Activity for result

Tags: android, android-activity, start-activity

It may be a noob question but I have some doubt. I googled a lot but found nothing.
In starting activity for result we pass request code and on result we check with the same request code and result code. I want to know Is there a way to Implement to perform different tasks and get different results from called activity by using request code i.e if the same activity is called many times with different request code then it returns different result. Please tell me how to do that. I found no way to have a switch statement or any other way to do this.

I already know the answers so editing this. I want to know If I can use the scenario like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourClass.class); 
intent.putExtras(b);
if(condition1)
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
else
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

And my called Activity returns two differnt results for request code 1 and 2 , So I can have

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //could replace it with a switch
    if (requestCode == 1){
        //condition 1
            }
        else if(requestCode == 2){
          //condition2
        }
}
```

i.e calling the same activity with different request code to get different results from the same activity.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return a result (startActivityForResult) from a TabHost Activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497205/how-to-return-a-result-startactivityforresult-from-a-tabhost-activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question posted was not so clear to me, You can always switch an activityForResult and check for activity result in onActivityResult method checking different request codes. Here is a code demonstration, how to do it:

Switch activity using this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourClass.class); 
intent.putExtras(b);    // here
startActivityForResult(intent, 2); //put your code along : positive integer
```

Check for result in this method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //could replace it with a switch
    if (requestCode == 1){
        //put your code here
            }
}
```

The called activity does not need to know your requestcode, however, if you want to do something like that, you can do that by passing your request code in intent, like this:

```
intent.putExtra("requestCode", requestCode);
```

Hence, access the intent variable in the activity class you switched onto..

Comment: You might want to make an edit to you original post..that would make things more clear

Comment: yes, ofcourse you can do that, you can startActivityForResult using different requestcodes depending on your requirement and check them vice versa in OnActivityResult..

Comment: How can I implement that in called activity thats what I have doubt about. Can you give example HOW to do it based on request code in called activity. How should I use setResult() under different conditions based on request code in called Activity.

Comment: you should go through [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104269/in-startactivityforresult-how-to-get-requestcode-from-child) for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if( requestCode == 1888 ) {

    }
}
```

OR

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode)
        case ACTIVITY1:
           if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activity 1 returned OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           break;
        case ACTIVITY2:
           if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activity 2 returned OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you want to do, but what I know is that you can return any code you want from to the first activity.
For example assuming you have an activity A, A call `startActivityForResult()` to activity B, then B do whatever stuff it has been made for, and then return a `resultCode`, that `resultCode` could be anything you want, such as 7, 8, 9.... whatever.
Then if you want your activity to do a specific stuff, then you can also start it with a custom requestCode, so when onActivityResult() is called you can check whether or not the activity returns what you wanted or not.
To do this I encourage you to use static integer values like `RESULT_1`, `RESULT_2`...

NOTE: You have to return positive values if you want `onActivityResult()` from the first activity to be called. Then just use a switch to handle differents `resultCode` values.