# Call fragment method inside an activity from another activity

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity

I have an `Activity` **A** with a `Fragment` and an `Activity` **B**.

When I click a button inside the Fragment, the Activity **B** is starting and i assume that the Activity **A** is `onPause`.

What I want to do is to click on a button inside the Activity **B** which will `finish()` this Activity and then go back to the Activity **A**.

Doing so would automatically call a method inside the fragment. After research I tried to implements `Interface` and Fragment transactions but I always get null objects.

How can I make my activities communicating and pass the information to the fragment in this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `ActivityB` from `FragmentA` (which is part of `ActivityA`) as `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()` call.

Using this, you would be able to pass back result from `Activity B` to `Fragment A`.

`Fragment A` (Part of `ActivityA`) :

```
// Calling Activity B
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class); 
intent.putExtras(b);    
startActivityForResult(intent, ANY_ID);

// Overriding callback for result
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == ANY_ID && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // Your logic of receiving data from Activity B
    }
}
```

**Important Point** : The `Fragment A` is the one making the startActivityForResult() call, but it is part of `Activity A` so `Activity A` gets the first shot at handling the result. It has to call `super.onActivityResult()` so that the callback can come to `Fragment A`

In `Activity A` :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // This is required, in order to get onActivityResult callback in Fragment A
}
```

Setting result back from `Activity B` :

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
// You can pass any data via this intent's bundle by putting as key-value pair
resultIntent.putExtra("Key", Value);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Reference :

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22554156/1994950
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6147919/1994950
3. [Start Activity for result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11860074/1994950)