# Is there a way for an Activity to know with what resultCode it was started?

Tags: android, android-activity

Looking all around, I can't seem to find any way for an `Activity` to determine with what `resultCode` it was started. Example:

```
class A extends Activity {
   void yadda() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
      startActivityForResult(intent, 8675309);
   }
}


class B extends Activity {
   void yadda() {
      int code = getTheResultCode(); // I want to get 8675309
   }
}
```

Do I have to put it into the `Intent`?

```
intent.putExtra("resultCode", 8675309);
```

Comment: The int parmeter in `startActivityForResult` will be available in `onActivityResult` method of activity `A` when activity `B` is finished. Take a look at a reference here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities. In your case, you should rather put it explicitly in the intent, as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In StartActivityForResult how to get requestCode from child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104269/in-startactivityforresult-how-to-get-requestcode-from-child)

Comment: So it is. Accepted, close away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Activity that knows the resultCode:

```
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class); 
  i.putExtra("resultCode",resultCode); 
  startActivity(i);
```

In the next Activity

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
  if (extras != null) { 
     String resultCode= extras.getString("resultCode"); 
  }
```