# How can different activities pass data to the same class?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two buttons.

`Button1` go to A then C

`Button2` go to A then B and finally C.

There are values pass between these activities. The problem I faced now is how do I check whether they are data pass from B to C or it is from  A to C only so I can set different condition to them.

**Activity A**

```
  btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  //if button1 is clicked
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),C.class);  //pass spinner value and date to next class
                Name = name.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Weather = weather.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Status=status.getSelectedItem().toString();
                intent.putExtra("Name",Name);
                intent.putExtra("Weather",Weather);
                intent.putExtra("Status",Status);
                intent.putExtra("date2",date2);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

   btnForce.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  { // if button2 clicked
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),B.class);
                Name = name.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Weather = weather.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Status=status.getSelectedItem().toString();
                intent.putExtra("Name",Name);
                intent.putExtra("Weather",Weather);
                intent.putExtra("Status",Status);
                intent.putExtra("date2",date2);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**Activity B**

```
 goDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { // if next button is clicked
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), C.class);
                sub = SubContractors.getText().toString();
                noP = NoPerson.getText().toString();
                noH=NoHours.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("sub",sub);
                intent.putExtra("noP",noP);
                intent.putExtra("noH",noH);
                intent.putExtra("name",name);
                intent.putExtra("weather",weather);
                intent.putExtra("status",status);
                intent.putExtra("date",date);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Activity c**

```
        name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name"); // receive name from Information
        weather = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Weather"); //receive weather
        date = getIntent().getExtras().getString("date2"); //receive date
        status = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Status"); // receive status
```

If has data passes from B, what should I write ?

Comment: Add one more key like "from" in Intent and check in C from which Activity Data C launched

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK can you show me some example ? Thanks

Comment: no example required i think you can do it yourself. like add  ` intent.putExtra("from","A");`  on Button `btnNext ` Click and same way add ` intent.putExtra("from","B");`  on Button `goDetails ` Click . In C check it as `String strFrom = getIntent().getExtras().getString("from"); if(strFrom.equals("A")){//from A}else if(strFrom.equals("B")){//from B}`

Comment: @MrsEd I saw the link you gave , but sadly it cannot applied to my case

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK If I write `intent.putExtra("from","A");` ,should I write   `intent.putExtra("Name",Name);
                intent.putExtra("Weather",Weather);
                intent.putExtra("Status",Status);
                intent.putExtra("date2",date2);` ? Or the `form` already include everything ?

Comment: @Tony: Yes right rest is same you have previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass some value to know from where the call came from.
You can uses example ρяσѕρєя K gave you. Or better jet try

> startActivityForResult(_new, REQUEST_CODE);

And then

> getIntent().getAction()

Take a look at this post to see more examples:
[Using startActivityForResult, how to get requestCode in child activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104269/in-startactivityforresult-how-to-get-requestcode-from-child)